# regex not working for fetching dates

Tags: grep, regular-expression

My file sample1.txt contains the below data:

```
2017-12-08
2017-12-31
2016-12-31
201707-31
2017-08-31
2017-08 -31
2017-0008-31
2017 08abcd 31
2017 0812-31
2017 -08- 31
```

I want to fetch date starting with 2017 and ending with 31 having '08' in between. I am using the below regex in grep to fetch those dates, but it's not working.

```
grep -E '^2017(08)+31$' sample1.txt
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `(08)+` to match?

Comment: i want dates starting with 2017 , ending with 31 and having 08 in between.. like 2017-08-31, 20170831,2017 -08 31,e.t.c.

Comment: Taking your specification literally, that would be: `'^2017.*08.*31$'`, in other words: '2017', anything, '08', anything, '31')... But I suspect you have restrictions on the "anything" part.

Comment: i don't have any restrictions on the anything part, i just thought that it would work with the regex i have given.

Comment: if i give the command "grep '08' sample1.txt" it would fetch all dates having "08" in it, irrespective of its position in the line, then by that logic regex '^2017(08)+31$' should also fetch dates having "08", no matter what it's position is excluding the first and the last position.

Answer (score 3):

> starting with 2017 and ending with 31 having '08' in between

- Start with 2017 - `^2017`
- Then have something or nothing - `.*`
- Then have 08 - `08`
- Then have something or nothing - `.*`
- Then end with 31 - `31$`

Putting this all together

```
^2017.*08.*31$
```

I don't see where you could have got `(08)+` from. In an Extended RE this defines a pattern that consists of one or more `08` sequences. For example, `08` or `0808` or even `080808080808080808`.

Comment: if i give the command "grep '08' sample1.txt" it would fetch all dates having "08" in it, irrespective of its position in the line, then by that logic regex '^2017(08)+31$' should also fetch dates having "08", no matter what it's position is excluding the first and the last position.

Comment: @PankajPandey no

Comment: @roaimia , can u tell me the reason for that?

Comment: @PankajPandey the last paragraph in my answer explains what your `(08)+` sequence does.